# Dynamically add new HTML elements on page load after getting JSON data from Web API

Tags: javascript, html, json, cordova

I'm building an hybrid Android App using Phonegap/Apache Cordova. My app should get data from my web api. I'm using JSON to serve the data to the APP. So i got a the following code:

```
function init() { 
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
var url = "http://23.21.128.153:3000/regions.json";var jsonresults;
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        jsonresults = data;
          $.each(jsonresults, function(i,v){
          $('#main-content').append('<li>'+jsonresults[i].name+'</li>');
        });
    });
}
```

and also on the body of the html i have a div called main-content. Everythings works fine in the Eclipse browser, but on the Android Emulator is not working. Not sure if there's another way to pull data from Web API using JSON and dinamically create HMTL elements after getting the data.

https://gist.github.com/2956660

Comment: You need to check for errors in `Logcat` first. Found the error's log, read it then come back with a real question after google'd it first of course :)

Comment: I'm sorry, probably I didn't phrase my issue well enough, since English is not my native tongue, but there's no errors in the Logcat. Would posting a gist with all my code help?

Comment: That'd be great for those who wish to help

Comment: have you included the ip address in the whilelist?? Please check this guide and  make sure the ip address you are refering is whitelisted in your project http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to get data from web api. Try this code. It will solve your problem,

It is very easy through jquery mobile. You can do your job with normal Ajax and little bit of JSON. I done with php server. Here the sample code,

Sending request to server through jquery.

```
$.ajax({
          url: <your Server URL>,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
          timeout: 5000,
          success: function(data, status){
                             /*Process your response here*/

      jsonresults = data;
      $.each(jsonresults, function(i,v){
      $('#main-content').append('<li>'+jsonresults[i].name+'</li>');
    });

 $.mobile.changePage($('#index')); /*page navigate the particular where data shown*/
 $("#index").trigger("pagecreate"); /*This is like a page refresh and load the injected data in jquery*/
                        }
       });
```

In php server file,

```
<?php
$data="I am sending response to you";

/*you have to mention this callback compulsory*/

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');';
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I got it to work. But now my issue is that I'm trying to build a Navbar with the data i got from the server but it doesnt get rendered like the Jquery Mobile navbar im getting a plain list. Here's the code I'm using to create the Navbar. https://gist.github.com/2962277

Comment: just take a look in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103426/persistent-jquery-mobile-navbar/11114142#11114142